# Modem PPP: The modem is not responding to "AT" at ModemCmd: label

Tags: pfsense

I am trying to install a 3g modem in pfsense, the huawei e173, but seems to be complicated to let it communicate through it.

After the installation of the 3g modem in Interfaces/Interface Assignments/PPPs,

http://prntscr.com/efkgfl

http://prntscr.com/efkgjy

i came back to Interfaces/Interface Assignments and added a new interface,

http://prntscr.com/efkh0z

after that, I went in Status/Interfaces and realised that I was unable to connect it, so i check Status/System Logs/PPP logs and saw that there was this error, but cannot figure out why since this modem is compatible:

```
 Mar 3 15:22:40   ppp      [opt5_link0] Link: reconnection attempt 7 in 1 seconds
Mar 3 15:22:41   ppp      [opt5_link0] Link: reconnection attempt 7
Mar 3 15:22:56   ppp      [opt5_link0] CHAT: The modem is not responding to "AT" at ModemCmd: label.
Mar 3 15:22:56   ppp      [opt5_link0] MODEM: chat script failed
Mar 3 15:22:56   ppp      [opt5_link0] Link: DOWN event
Mar 3 15:22:56   ppp      [opt5_link0] LCP: Down event
```

From the 3 links of interfaces that shows up when I plugin this modem (cuaU0, cuaU1 and cuaU2), regarding that error from cuaU0, in cuaU0 there was this one:

```
Mar 3 15:27:40   ppp      [opt5_link0] Link: reconnection attempt 1 in 2 seconds
Mar 3 15:27:42   ppp      [opt5_link0] Link: reconnection attempt 1
Mar 3 15:27:43   ppp      [opt5_link0] CHAT: +CGDCONT=1,"IP","noapn"
Mar 3 15:27:43   ppp      [opt5_link0] CHAT: Detected Hayes compatible modem.
Mar 3 15:27:43   ppp      [opt5_link0] CHAT: The modem responded with "ERROR" to the command "AT&F&C1&D2E0S0=0M1" at ModemCmd: label.
Mar 3 15:27:43   ppp      [opt5_link0] MODEM: chat script failed
Mar 3 15:27:43   ppp      [opt5_link0] Link: DOWN event
Mar 3 15:27:43   ppp      [opt5_link0] LCP: Down event
```

and in cua01:

```
MODEM: Fail to open serial port /dev/cuaU0 on speed 115200
```

In console I have the device as:

```
<HUAWEI Mobile HUAWEI> at usbus0, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=            HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=ON (500mA)

  bLength = 0x0012
  bDescriptorType = 0x0001
  bcdUSB = 0x0200
  bDeviceClass = 0x0000  <Probed by interface class>
  bDeviceSubClass = 0x0000
  bDeviceProtocol = 0x0000
  bMaxPacketSize0 = 0x0040
  idVendor = 0x12d1
  idProduct = 0x1c05
  bcdDevice = 0x0102
  iManufacturer = 0x0002  <HUAWEI>
  iProduct = 0x0001  <HUAWEI Mobile>
  iSerialNumber = 0x0000  <no string>
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the compatible list (https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Known_Working_3G-4G_Modems) I notice that this version is not compatible.

Just to let you all know, this version is a **Huawei E173S-1** with an **idProduct = 0x1c05**

This idProduct was extracted through console with the following command line:

```
usbconfig dump_device_desc
```